# SPFX corrupted solution

Tags: spfx

We are thinking of leveraging SPFx for our business.

I have created a solution with an SPFx web part. The hello world solution worked as expected.

After a couple of days I returned  to the solution to add a second web-part. 
While running yo @microsoft/sharepoint I get an error

> C:\Users\vasileios.kantartzis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\pad-component\index.js:28

What is wrong here? I have seen the same behavior on multiple boxes

If I create a new solution in a new folder I do not have this issue

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

it might cause by version differences. You can try to check the version and update your existing solution package version if necessary.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/update-latest-packages

After updated, try to add the second web part again.